# ACL and Drupal roles

Tags: drupal, acl

I'm having trouble to correctly setup ACL and Drupal roles (Civicrm 4.6.35 on Drupal 7)

I have my contacts assigned to different groups (let's say G1 ... G5)
For each group there is a corresponding responsible group (GR1 ... GR5)
People assigned to the GR1 are allowed to edit contacts in G1 but are not allowed to see contacts from the other groups (unless they are member of the related GR group)
I've created an ACL role RespG1, assigned this role to GR1 and gave this permission to edit G1 contacts.
The drupal user which is memeber of GR1 has no extra Drupal roles.

I thought this would work but the user doesn't see any contacts at all.
When I give the Authenticated drupal role permission to see all contacts this overrules the ACL and he can see all contacts but that is not the purpose.

What am I missing?

Comment: Your approach sounds right.  Could you add a few screenshots to help us spot what is wrong?

Comment: This is an old question and I suspect you've either moved on or found an answer. If you found how to do it, please could add an answer, even if it was somethign simple (e.g. rebuild ACL permissions, clear caches) or delete the question if you are not still looking for an answer?